# Is the statement "Nothing is absolute" a contradiction?

Tags: logic

When we say "Nothing is absolute", we actually stated that "Everything is absolutely not absolute", is this a contradiction?

Comment: Absolutely! [character fillerrrrrrr]

Comment: Can you fill in the logic that connects the two quoted statements?

Comment: It's more of a simplification...

Comment: Only if nothingness itself isn't intended as absolute.

Comment: This sentence is too vague to be a statement, let alone a contradiction. Who knows what "nothing" means and whether it applies to objects, statements or something else. Nor does it contain "is absolutely not absolute", so whatever it asserts it may do so not "absolutely" (whatever that means) but contextually. And this is how "nothing is absolute" is usually meant when used colloquially, in which case it may be specific enough to be a statement, and it won't be a contradiction.

Comment: I find the statements muddled. It is possible to say that no 'thing' is absolute thus that 'nothing' is absolute, yet at the same time say that there is an absolute that is not a thing thus that the absolute is not nothing. It's the different meanings of 'Nothing' that cause the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is a contradiction. Take as an example "Nothing is true". Stating the latter would mean that even that affirmation is false, and therefore its exact opposite would be true (we know from Aristotle's Metaphysics that there is no grey area in regards to the terms of a contradiction; so if one is false, the other one must be true).

Following this line of thought, the affirmation "Nothing is absolute" would imply that itself is relative, and therefore a subject of relative truth.

Moreover, stating that everything else is relative, but this affirmation is absolute ("Nothing is absolute, excepting this affirmation.") is an obvious absurdity.

For a very detailed analysis on why "Nothing is true" (and analogously "Nothing is absolute") lacks any logic, I can refer you to Aristotle's Metaphysics, Book IV, Chapter 5, reference point 1009b.

Comment: "Nothing is absolute" cannot be an absolute statement, so you cannot deduce that it means absolutely and exactly what you think it means.  'Nothing' and 'everything' only have meaning within a domain of reference *which makes them implicitly relative and therefore not absolute*.  Yes, even that statement itself is not absolutely true, because it does not apply to cows, or bridges, only statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the statement 'nothing is absolute' implies everything is relative but states literally 'nothing is absolute', hence a contradiction.

Comment: This really lack any grounding in philosophy or even in logic.  It is circular reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is impossible to deny the existence of truth, because in doing so, you have created a statement that must be objectively true in order for you to hold that point of view.

Comment: This is also circular reasoning.  If you assume absolute meaning, you can find a contradiction between your assumption and this phrase.  But that is not a contradiction within the phrase itself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54017/discussion-on-answer-by-piomicron-is-the-statement-nothing-is-absolute-a-contr).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with whether the notion of 'everything' or 'nothing' is ever properly to be taken as an absolute notion.  We cannot imagine 'absolutely everything' or 'absolutely nothing', and in an important sense, they cannot exist.

We can keep imagining more and more, and therefore can't state what really is everything.  So why presume there is such a thing as everything.  Or we keep thinking we have gotten to nothing, only to realize there is really something there (empty space, the rules of geometry, the idea of rules, the idea of ideas, the possibility of ideas, the possibility of possibilities, the idea of possibilities, ...)  So again, why presume there is such a thing as nothing.

If existence or nonexistence exists, in the same way other things exist, then we find existence to be a property and we dig ourselves into the wide, deep hole of [Meinongianism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/) or other [modal realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/david-lewis/) from which there is virtually no escape.  You get to questions like whether unicorns are absolutely not real, or whether there are numerous ways not to be real, and which rules of logic apply to things that are fictional vs thing that are more thoroughly unreal.  And then you wish you hadn't started.

It is instead preferable to see universality and negation as an extrapolation and misleading oversimplification of the real ideas of distinction and inclusion, and therefore as the idealized version of something that is real, like infinity or 'redness', but not real things in themselves.  They are directions and not destinations.

This fits with the '[mathematical fictionalist](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism-mathematics/)' take on quantification.  There is no set of everything to quantify over, and the empty set is really a thing and not nothing, but we can make statements of implication containing free variables that preserve understanding, because the objects that back them up either exist in some limited way, or they do not, and in either case, the implication holds -- in the one case because of logic, in the other because of the vacuous truth of implication by falsehoods.

It is not a contradiction to say 'Given a type of thing that exists, among that type, if it has multiple elements, there is some range of variation or exceptional states.  And if does not have multiple elements, it is an unnecessary extravagance, which should be eliminated by Occam's razor.'  But what it means depends upon context that defines your ability to quantify things.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53858/discussion-on-answer-by-jobermark-is-the-statement-nothing-is-absolute-a-contr).

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is perhaps too meandering.  There is a shorter way to address this question.

Given the assumption that words mean *absolutely exactly* what you mean by them, the idea that nothing is absolute yields a contradiction.  But it is not within the proposition itself, it is with your preceding assumption.

In translating the one form of this statement into the other, you are already assuming the definitions of some words are absolute.  By assuming the exact opposite of anything, (that there exists words with an absolute meaning) and then considering that thing, *if course* you will get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The truth value of a statement depends greatly on the interpretation, and that turns out to be important here.

If you approach this from the perspective that one can meaningfully make absolute statements, then "nothing is absolute" has all the hallmarks of being one of those statements.  If it is an absolute and true, then a paradox forms, for then there is at least one counterexample.  If it is absolute and false, then no paradox forms, for it's simply a false statement.

If you approach this from the perspective that one cannot meaningfully make absolute statements, then a phrase such as "nothing is absolute" must be taken as literary license on a relative phrase.  As such, it forms no paradox because it was already not an absolute.

Thus, what we can say is that the statement "nothing is absolute" can only be true if you already believe it, and must be false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a contradiction, and it arises from the fact that the statement is self-referent (in saying that nothing is absolute, the statement is also asserting that itself is not absolute). Self-reference will commonly lead to such kind of contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is absolute or ‘true’ as another answer points out, then the universe we live in is utterly incomprehensible. We can’t speak about anything with any intelligibility.

Following the laws of thought or laws of logic that originated with Aristotle, something can’t both be true and false. (See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought) Absolutely the way something is and the way it is not. Either something is a certain way or it is not. Of course, there are logics that do not incorporate the Law or Excluded Middle (intuinisitic and paraconsistent). But this isn’t the direction this line of reasoning seems to be heading.

But before you get to this point, you have to come up with a coherent definition of absolute. I know Hegel talked about ‘the Absolute’ a lot. ‘The absolute is lazy’? What could that even mean. Very unclear and vague and unnecessarily esoteric use of language to me. If you define something being absolutely the way it is, there are no qualifications and A=A (the Law of Identity). If A does not equal A, then you’ve found yourself in a reductio ad absurdum or a true contradiction (a dialetheism).

We also can’t be sure we can have certain knowledge of anything. We can probably be absolutely sure that we exist in some capacity otherwise we couldn’t be having these thoughts (a la Descartes).